# Remove $promise and $resolved from json object not working

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm getting data from the server using `$resource` like this

service

```
.factory('rulesService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var systems = $resource('url');
    return systems;
}]);
```

controller

```
$scope.rules= rulesService.query();
console.log($scope.rules);
```

The output I get is

```
0: Resource
1: Resource
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
length: 2
```

I tried to strip `$promise` & `$resolved` using

1) `angular.toJson($scope.rules)`

2)`JSON.stringify($scope.rules, null, 2)`

Both these are returning  `[]`

Can someone help me on this

Comment: why do you want to strip them?

Comment: @MuliYulzary I want to access it using the key. Like $scope.rules[0]. It is returning undefined when these things are there

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments above, I think your problem is you use $resource wrong.

$resource will return a empty object or array, and then make the http call in the background and populate the array/object once it is complete.

This means that, at the time you console.log the object, it is actually an empty array, but since the log in the browser is pretty smart, it will update the object in the log as well, once the $resource call is done.

this is why console.log(rules[0]) is undefined, while console.log(rules) says the element exists. It didn't at the time of the log.

If you need to do further processing you have to do something like:

```
var rules = rulesService.query(function () {
  console.log(rules[0])
})
```

you can also use promises instead of a callback, but either way you need to ensure the data is fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply iterate over the array (and ignore the extra properties). If you want a clean array you could always use a map or similar.

```
$scope.new_rules = $scope.rules.map(function (rule){
  return rule;
})
```

Comment: It is not iterating over the array. 

$scope.new_rules = $scope.ruless.map(function (rule) {
              console.log(rule);
              return rule;
          }).

The console.log is not getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to asynchronous execution and race conditions.

You're trying to refer to `rules[0]` before data actually arrives from the `$resource.query()` call.

Examples:

```
var rules = rulesService.query();
console.log(rules[0]); //will print nothing. the GET request hasn't been resolved yet.

rules.$promise.then(function (response) {
 console.log(rules[0]); //This WILL work assuming you actually get data from the backend.
 console.log(response[0]); //This will also work with the same data.
});
```